# Filtering Data from one workbook to another workbook and sheet within the second workbook in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

All data is consolidated in this sheet via apps script (code below)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y48N8W8CdaNlrxXopj5lnHTiNep33g_qA2-kTrPdt3A/edit#gid=130911536

I need from this data all the rows that don't contain 'completed' per unique name. This data gets put here with columns 1,2,3,5,and 11: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brmAUrtF4Hu18X4bGYGekdEl8g4Sx1Eke5Q6KctJ4NU/edit#gid=0

If archive is no and Column E contains completed, I need put in the Sheet 'Projects to Archive' in the original workbook with the same columns, 1,2,3,5, and 11

I need each thing only copied once. No duplicates.

App script code:

```
function combineSheets() {
  const sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
                 'August','September','October','November','December'];  
  const master = sApp.getSheetByName('Master');          
  const sourceData = [];
  months.forEach(m=>{
     let sh = sApp.getSheetByName(m);
     let vals = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),27).getValues().filter(r=>r[1]!='');
       sourceData.push(...vals);
  });
  master.getRange(1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand `If archive is no and Column E contains completed, I need put in the Sheet 'Projects to Archive' in the original workbook with the same columns, 1,2,3,5, and 11` and your current issue. And also, I cannot understand the relationship between your script, your sample Spreadsheets and goal. I apologize for this. And also, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, in your 1st Spreadsheet, there are 9 sheets. In your 2nd Spreadsheet, 1 sheet and no values in the sheet. In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: The code doesn’t matter, I just included it so there were no questions. All the data is coming from the consolidated data sheet. The second spreadsheet is for the data to be sorted to as stated in my original post. I just need a way for all the data to get to the sheet the way I mentioned. Let me know if that clears any confusion.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: No worries. I will try to reword to make less confusing. Thanks

Comment: Here are some examples of how I want my final sheets to look: https://imgur.com/a/vQsWL6a   (colors are just for making it easier to explain) Let me know if this is less confusing. Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. But I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Are those the sample output situations? If it's so, can I ask you about the sample input situation you expect? From the sample input and output situation, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Those are output. The input is the first sheet I linked.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic for achieving from the sample input to the sample output you provided. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to try to understand about the logic. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: its fine. I'll start a new question with my details.